# Contains method in Java doesn't exist?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a java script for a mobile app check if a string contains specific characters.

```
if(fn.contains(" ")){

}
```

The `fn` variable is declared twice in the following:

```
private EditText fn;
final EditText fn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fn);
```

Not sure why this doesn't work. In android studio, the `contains` function highlights red as it doesn't exist. You can click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6whGy.png) to see what I am talking about. Is there another method than this?

Comment: Include the declaration of `fn` in the post, and ensure you aren't shadowing the `String` type

Comment: Java doesn't have scripts.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two different languages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Comment: @KALALEX He never said JavaScript. He said a Java script (a script written in Java)

Answer (score 0):

That is an EditText not a string you must do first:

```
var str = fn.getText().toString()

if(str.indexOf(" ") !== -1;){ . . . }
```

Comment: When you put this, it worked:  fn.getText().toString().contains(" ")

Comment: dont tell you did this .. fn.contains(" ").getText().toString() xD

Comment: When you first said, I accidentally forgot to add the toString()